# How to display names in alphabetical order in CollectionView

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, ios10.3

I have a list of names in an array, I want to display them on a collection view in alphabetical order. And also to show the alphabet for each of the section how can I achieve this. 
[Click here for Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHYLm.png)

Answer (score 1):

Here are my assumptions about what you already have:

1. you have a model class (`Model`) with a property `name`
2. the data-structure behind your `UICollectionView` is an array of `Model` objects

Here's what I'd do:

1. sort the `Model` array by its `name` property.

   ```
   sortedModels = models.sorted(by: { (first, second) -> Bool in
     return first.title.compare(second.title) == ComparisonResult.orderedAscending
   }
   ```
2. create a new property to hold the UICollectionView data, where the dictionary key is a single letter ("A", for example), and an array of section names which will contain the sections in the correct order. This will be the section title in the collection view

   ```
   var data = Dictionary<Character, [Model]>()
   var sections = [Character]
   ```
3. iterate through `sortedList`, checking the first character of the `name` property, then either creating a new array in the dictionary (if the key doesn't already exist) or adding the `Model` to an existing array

   ```
   models.forEach { (model) in
       let firstCharacter = model.name.characters.first!
       if var array = data[firstCharacter] {
           array.append(model)
           data[firstCharacter] = array
       } else {
           var array = [Model]()
           array.append(model)
           data[firstCharacter] = array
           sections.append(firstCharacter)
       }
   }
   ```
4. then your `numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:` would return the number of keys in the dictionary
5. and `collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:` would return the number of items in the sections array

Comment: Please, just use `first.title < second.title` instead of `first.title.compare(second.title) == ComparisonResult.orderedAscending`.